How to Assign Role to New User with Graph API
I have a React App and .NET 8 Web API with their own app registrations in an MS Entra External ID tenant. Authentication is done using msal-react and I'm using Microsoft.Identity.Web on the backend.
I'd like to programmatically assign a role to a user after they've successfully registered as certain Web API endpoints require this role for authz. I've been looking at MS documentation but am a little stuck on the overall picture of how to implement it.
This MS article shows the following code to send a request to assign the role via Graph API:
// Dependencies
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var requestBody = new AppRoleAssignment
{
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse("cde330e5-2150-4c11-9c5b-14bfdc948c79"),
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse("8e881353-1735-45af-af21-ee1344582a4d"),
    AppRoleId = Guid.Parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
};

// To initialize your graphClient, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-client?from=snippets&tabs=csharp
var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].AppRoleAssignments.PostAsync(requestBody);


Based on that I have to create a Graph Client using OBO that I found in this MS article it looks like this:
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
// single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
var tenantId = "common";

// Values from app registration
var clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
var clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

// using Azure.Identity;
var options = new OnBehalfOfCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

// This is the incoming token to exchange using on-behalf-of flow
var oboToken = "JWT_TOKEN_TO_EXCHANGE";

var onBehalfOfCredential = new OnBehalfOfCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, oboToken, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(onBehalfOfCredential, scopes);


So, in my Web API code I need to get the PrincipalId of the user, ResourceId of the Web API (where the App Roles were created), and the AppRoleId to be able to send the request.
I haven't used Graph API before so I wanted to check that if this is the correct way of going about it such that the access token for the user gets updated/returned with the new role added to the roles claim to be used to successfully hit the endpoints requiring said role when the user makes a request to it.
Does this look correct and/or am I missing anything? I believe I may need to add another Graph API scope to the second code snippet but any guidance is helpful as I navigate this interesting world of MS Graph.

Your approach is correct for adding application roles to users.
For the second snippet you will need additional scopes as described in the documentation.
AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All and Application.Read.All would be the least privileged combination.
Note this applies if you are calling Graph API on behalf of a user; if you wanted to do this with only application credentials, it'd require the application permissions with same names (instead of delegated permissions aka scopes).
Make sure the ResourceId matches the object ID of the target API service principal.

Okay thank you for your advice, I will try that.
Is the flow of user being authenticated/receiving access token -> being redirected to redirectUrl which is a React component that sends a request to the backend code with above Graph API logic correct?
I'm still quite new to authn/authz and remember reading something about "redirectUrl should be a blank page" but I may be misremembering and/or having incorrect idea of hitting Graph API code after user registration as it seems like an extra API call from React to  backend.
I can make this another question as well as it's lengthy.

Ah ok so you have something like a UI for assigning roles? Something like: React UI -> API -> Graph API? That is totally ok but you will need to use the "on-behalf-of" flow in the back-end. Your second snippet currently shows that it is using DeviceCodeCredential which uses the device code flow. You'll probably want to use MSAL.js in the front-end (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react). In the back-end you can either use MSAL directly or Microsoft.Identity.Web library.

It's not that the roles are chosen in the front end (if that's what you meant) as I currently want any user to be assigned one role for now when they register.
My apologies, I should have said I am using the msal-react library and Microsoft.Identity.Web on the backend. I had a feeling that DeviceCodeCredential didn't seem right as the user is authenticated when they register through the React app and after registration I want to add the specific role to their token claims to avoid manually doing this in the portal.
So this setup would require OBO flow?

OBO is required when you have something like front-end -> back-end -> another API. The back-end can use OBO to get a token for another API on behalf of the user that signed in to the front-end.

Ahhh, okay. So user authenticates in React and their returned ID token is for the Web API. Now the Web API needs OBO to send a request to Graph API with the user's information. And once the role is assigned, is a new token sent to user to send to the API with the role claim?
Anyway, thank you so much for your help! While I'm new to authn/authz, I was reading/doing articles/documentation/testing for days to figure this out lol and was told this wasn't an OBO situation, so this should get me going!

Yeah, the ID token/access token for the app where the role is registered will contain it. But keep in mind that existing tokens won't update immediately, it'll be once the token is refreshed.

Oh that's good to know. So a new access token would need to be issued for the user to be able to successfully hit secured API endpoints after they register/get assigned role, and if so I assume the refresh token can't be used for that (unless they can be used for more than expired tokens)?
